# Wikimedia Commons query stopped working

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I had this url for photo searches on Wikimedia Commons :

[`https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?
 action=query&
 prop=imageinfo|categories&
 generator=search&
 gimlimit=10&
 gsrsearch=File:"${title}"&
 iiprop=extmetadata|url&
 iiextmetadatafilter=ImageDescription|ObjectName&
 gsrnamespace=6&
 format=json&
 origin=*`](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=imageinfo|categories&generator=search&gimlimit=10&gsrsearch=File:"$%7Btitle%7D"&iiprop=extmetadata|url&iiextmetadatafilter=ImageDescription|ObjectName&gsrnamespace=6&format=jsonfm&origin=*)

where `${title}` is the search term.  It was working beautifully.  All of a sudden now it stopped working.  I get this error:

```
Unrecognized parameter: gimlimit
```

I tried taking that parameter out and now nothing gets returned at all.  This used to work.  What has changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter names look like `['g' for generator][module prefix][base parameter name]`. So if you want to limit the number of search results, that would be `gsrlimit`. If you want to limit the number of image revisions to return info for per search result, that would be `iilimit` (it defaults to 1 though so you probably don't need to change it).

As you can see from your own link, you go get results (and removing `gimlimit` does not change anything, beyond the warning not showing up).

Comment: Tgr I love you! You have saved my bacon!